# How to get visitor device Information

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, html

How to get complete device information of users using PHP or Javascript.

1. Device Info (Eg Mobile, PC, Tablet)
2. OS information (Eg Windows, Linux, Android, IOS)
3. Brand Name (Eg Samsung, Apple, Lenovo etc)
4. Browser (Eg Chrome, Firefox)
5. OS Version (Eg, Windows 8, windows 10, Android 8 etc)

Comment: Did you try dumping `$_SERVER`? Like `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat this dont provide information about brand name and OS information

Comment: I really doubt if you could even get correct information because this information can be manipulated by client and you just have to trust the information. About the brand name, I don't think that you would be able to get that information. You can also take a look at `get_browser()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can get easily using PHP.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Or,

```
$browserInfo = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browserInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Browsecap database for this purpose.

get_browser function from php uses user agent to get Information about device , os , browser etc.

You need to regularly update browsecap.ini file regularly to keep updated with latest Devices and Browsers.

Installation : download browsecap.ini from

https://browscap.org

Move file to

/etc/php.d/browscap.ini

Then add below lines to php.ini

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "/etc/php.d/browscap.ini"
```

Restart webserver to apply changes

And now you can use get_browser() function

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(); 
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links will help you get started on that issue
https://www.visitorjs.com/
https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/retrieving-visitor-information-javascript/